# How to port the program based on python27 to another pc(win7)?

Tags: python, c++, c, dll

I am writing a c++ program which depend on the python27, the exe works good on my pc, but it cannot load the python modules on another pc, it will pop out the error messages like "ImportError : No module named site".

What I have done are

1. copy the python27.dll, DLLs and Lib folders to another pc
2. append the path of python27.dll to the system variable "PATH"(c:/python27/DLLs)
3. Create a new system variable PYTHONPATH(c:/python27/DLLs;c:/python27/Lib)

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using py2exe? if configured properly, it should include code from the modules for you.

Comment: This is the first time I hear this name, trying to study it, could it convert the 3rd parties python Lib into exe too?